# How to order the data by physical fields in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Can `order by` in Apache IoTDB order by fields in time series, instead of ordering by time or device? I want to find the utility data distribution of a certain device during a certain period of time, and now I can only query out all the data during this period and then order the utility data by myself. I wonder if there is an easier way for me to know the distribution of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the distribution of data in Apache IoTDB, aside of using `max` and `min` functions, you can also use `Top K` to get the corresponding quantile you want. Also, you can try to use aggregate functions to know more, or write a program to get the data fields.